# count number of column in mongoDB using Java

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have installed `MongoDB` in my system and I inserted 10 documents into the `username` collection. That document contains `name`, `roll no`, `city` fields. I need to count the number of fields in the `username` collection.

I except 3... How to get the 3 from java program?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Java in your application you are manipulating DBObject ( http://api.mongodb.org/java/2.6/com/mongodb/DBObject.html ) and you can get the KeySet from this and the size will be the number of attributes. (in your case it will be 4 since you have the _id attribute)

But this is PER DOCUMENT, remember that in a collection, each document can have its own "structure", in your case one user could have 4 attributes, another could have 10... and some of them could have sub documents with their own structure. MongoDB does not have any "catalog".

Some system are "sampling" the data to analyze the global structure of the documents and provide a catalog but this is will not be exact.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
System.out.println(coll.getCount());
```

More Detail here: http://docs.mongodb.org/ecosystem/tutorial/getting-started-with-java-driver/

Comment: System.out.println(coll.getCount()); this command only get the number of row in the db.. I got the solution cursor.next().toMap().keySet().size();